# Values are null for ajax GET

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

This is not working, the values are `null` at the server.

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/PlayZone/GetCards',
    type: "GET",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'what': what, 'by': by, 'jump': jump }),
});
```

C#:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetCards(string what ,string by, string jump)
{
    ...
}
```

This is working fine, but I need the GET ajax work to like the post. Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/PlayZone/GetCards',
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'what': what, 'by': by, 'jump': jump }),
});
```

C#

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetCards(string what ,string by, string jump)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Any .success or .fail ???

Comment: Have you tried using an object instead of 3 separate parameters?

Comment: Don't stringify `data`. just pass the object - `data: { 'what': what, 'by': by, 'jump': jump },`

Comment: I don't know about the problem but what I'm sure is that it's a bad idea to use a `POST` to actually get something... maybe that's even part of the answer...

Comment: i am get error from ajax, but its insert GetCards func in controller in debug

Comment: You can't set the content-type of a GET request, there is no request body to describe the content of.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
              $.ajax({
                    url: '/PlayZone/GetCards',
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { what: what, by: by, jump: jump },
                    success: function (response) {
                              alert("success");
                    }
                });
```

Comment: This is a game of spot-the-difference. What did you change? Why should it help?

Comment: @Quentin: there is no need of `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: Why not? What has changed about the server side code which means it is no longer expecting JSON? For that matter, the question is asking about making a GET request and your code is making a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the value as below in your java script

```
data: {'what': what, 'by': by,'jump': jump }
```

Answer (score 0):

when using Get as your type, your only way of passing data to the server is via the url.

You can get away with it by doing something similar to this:

```
$.get("/PlayZone/GetCards", {what: what, by: by, jump: jump}).done(function(result) {});
```

Jquery will change the javascript object into querystring parameters to pass to your action.

The other way is build a url that has the query string parameters with dummy data, and then use replace on that string to add in your values.

Personally I'd go with the $.get solution